# DisplayPromptAsync Maui Cancel options

Tags: c#, maui

as soon as I click on the cancel on the Display it generates an error, System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```cs
private async void NameClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
   var ResultName = await DisplayPromptAsync("Insira seu Nome", "Favor inserir seu Nome","Ok", "Cancel");
   LabelName.Text = ResultName.ToString();
   await DisplayAlert("Nome Alterado","Seu Nome Foi altera com Sucesso","OK");
```

Apparently an exception needs to be created for " Cancel " but I still can't understand how I will create this exception if anyone can help me

It is finalizing the application as a whole

I was expecting the option to cancel finalize the displaypromptasync and not change anything.

Comment: Please format your code so it is readable

Comment: Please note this is not a C question. Please tag your next question correctly.

Comment: As the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pop-ups?view=net-maui-7.0#display-a-prompt) says: *"If the Cancel button is tapped, null is returned."*. Thus, `ResultName.ToString()` gives a null exception. Fix: check whether `ResultName` is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check if result is null

```
 var result = await DisplayPromptAsync(…);

 if (result != null)
 {
    // do stuff
 }
```

Comment: I tried to do that, but whenever I click " cancel " on the Display it returns that exception
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' in reference to my variable that changes the Label

`LabelName.Text = ResultName.ToString();`

Comment: that's why you check for null - if it's null then do NOT do that.  Put your code inside the if block

Comment: if you need more help, please edit your question to include the revised code you are using (and please format it so its readable)

Comment: @D3atHpR **1)** *"as soon as ... it returns that exception"*. Actually, that is not where it happens in CODE. Set a breakpoint on line `await DisplayPromptAsync...`. If you step through the code (F10), the exception happens on the **next** line. **2)** You can get Visual Studio to stop on the correct line: wrap all the code in that method inside `try { ...YOUR CODE HERE ... } catch (exception ex) {}`.  Use Debug/Window/ExceptionSettings to make sure all "Managed Exceptions" are ENABLED. Then it should stop by itself on the correct line.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I thought a little about what you commented and I did it and it worked, exactly as I wanted, thanks

Comment: If an answer helps you, please "Accept" it. (click "Checkmark" next to answer).